# Stop the music and the Service too

Tags: android, service

I'm trying to play a music using service in Android. What I'm struggling with is to stop the service and the music. Here is my service:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

public SoundService() {
    super("SoundService");
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.zenenegy);
}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    mediaPlayer.start();
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.release();
        }
    });
    return START_STICKY;
}

public void stopp(){
    Log.d("SERVICE","STOP");
    stopSelf();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

When I call the 'stopp' method I got the Log so the service should have stopped, but the music went on. I have no idea how to stop the music because when I tried to use mediPlayer.stop(); method I have always got error messages so it would be great if I could just stop the service whenever I want to. Here is the code of the Activity :

```
public Button zene;
public boolean hang = true;
SoundService soundService;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fomenu);

    if(hang){
        startService();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    zene = (Button)findViewById(R.id.zene);

    zene.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                if(hang){
                    soundService.stopp();
                    //soundService.onDestroy();
                }
            hang = !hang;
        }
    });
    super.onResume();
}

public void startService(){
    startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), SoundService.class));
}

public void stopService(){
    stopService(new Intent(getBaseContext(),SoundService.class));
}
```

}

I've tried to use stopService(); method too but it didn't work. If anyone has an idea how to stop the music in the service please response.

Comment: did you try calling mediaplayer.stop() and release in ondestroy

Comment: Yes and it didn't work.

Comment: try passing this in mediaplayer oncreate instead of getapplicationcontext()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SoundService.java

```
public void stop(){
  Log.d("SERVICE","STOP");
  mp.stop();
  //release the media player if you want to
  stopSelf();
}
```

A few ways of stopping would be to use [Bound Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) or in your `onStartCommand` recognize the intent action and then call `stop()`

It would look something like this

InYourActivity.java

```
public void stopService(){
    Intent stopIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),SoundService.class);
    intent.setAction(SoundService.ACTION_STOP);
    stopService(stopIntent);
}
```

SoundService.java

```
public static final String ACTION_STOP = "stop_music_service";

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if(intent.getAction()!=null && intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_STOP)){
       stop();
    }
    mediaPlayer.start();
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.release();
        }
    });
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to place your binding code?
`soundService.stopp();` how is soundService initialized/assigned?

Comment: Sorry but I dont know what is binding code. And I initialized soundService object on the top of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the stop method for the instance of the MediaPlayer object you have instantiated.  In your case your MediaPlayer object is called mediaPlayer.

Here is an example:

```
public void stopMusic(){
 if (mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
   mediaPlayer.stop();
   mediaPlayer.destroy();
 }
}
```

Comment: I am noticing you have at least two separate MediaPlayer objects instantiated, one is named mp and the other is named mediaPlayer. You probably should only create one MediaPlayer object.  This may be part of the problem.

Comment: @joshgoldeneagle the mp object is in reference to the same mediaplayer object that is returned by the listener. So its safe to have it there.